# Recurrence On finance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

A bank pays 6% interest at the end of each year on an account which initially starts with $2000.  Find a recurrence relation for, the amount of money in the account at the end of year n if

a) only if the yearly interest is added to the initial amount.

b) if an additional $2000 is put into the account at the end of each year as well as the yearly interest that is paid on the money in the account at the beginning of the year.

I know this is a recurrence problem but I'm not sure how to relate it to this finance problem

Comment: What have you tried? Can you write an equation relating money in 2 consecutive years?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  It isn't a finance problem-you have numbers to consider (that happen to be dollars).  If you have $x$ dollars in your account and the bank pays $6\%$ interest, how many dollars do you have now?  If you have $x$ dollars in the account and add $\$2000$ how many do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

Hint2: Notice that if no more money is added, after 1 period you'll have $2000 + r*2000$ dollars. this is the principal, plus the interests accrued after one period. In the second period, you'll have that quantity plus the interests accrued on it: $r*(2000+r*2000)$. You should be able to see a pattern and generalize this for $n$ periods.

A similar logic should help you see the pattern when you also add $2000$ dollars every period.